# How can apps tell that they are running on a rooted phone?

Tags: rooting

I've heard that some of them refuse to run on rooted devices.

One might think that a rooted device would be able to present itself as a non-rooted one. Is that not so?

Comment: Most of them use SafetyNet. See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/161454/96277

Comment: @Firelord detecting `su` binary is more straightforward. Though SafetyNet provides additional integrity checks in one place, like bootloader unlock status, CTS certification, custom ROM etc. So is more preferable for developers.

Comment: There's a competition going on between both parties. Rooting solutions (particularly Magisk) have gone too far to make sure AMAP to hide root existence from apps which don't like it. It involves hiding modifications during boot, watching `zygote` & manipulating apps' mount namesapces. OTOH Google built a standalone service in Play Services (`gms.unstable` / SafetyNet) which does its best to detect root presence. So far the first party seems to be dominant but in fact it's very hard (or impossible) to hide root presence at least from native Android processes which are themselves running as root